# How to align widgets contained on several HBoxLayouts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Let's consider this little snippet:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class PropertiesWidget(QTreeView):

    def __init__(self, columns, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PropertiesWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.setColumnCount(columns)
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Property")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Value")
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.last_item = 0
        self.last_item = QStandardItem()
        self.parameters = {}

    def begin_group(self, name, key):
        root = QStandardItem(name)
        root.setEditable(False)
        if not key:
            root.setData(key)
        self.model.appendRow([root])
        self.last_item = root

    def end_group(self):
        if (self.last_item and self.last_item.parent()):
            self.last_item = self.last_item.parent()

    def append_row(self, text, widget):
        if not self.last_item:
            return

        if text in self.parameters:
            raise Exception("Not allowed duplicate keys {0}".format(text))

        item = self.last_item
        child = QStandardItem(text)
        child2 = QStandardItem()
        child.setEditable(False)
        item.appendRow([child, child2])
        if widget:
            self.setIndexWidget(child2.index(), widget)

        self.expand(child.index().parent())

    def add_vec2(self, key, value):
        x = QLineEdit(value, self)
        y = QLineEdit(value, self)

        lbl = QLabel('')
        lbl.setMinimumWidth(0)
        lbl2 = QLabel('')
        lbl2.setMinimumWidth(0)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(x, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(y, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(lbl, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(lbl2, stretch=1)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        widget = QWidget(self)
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        setattr(widget, "operator_key", key)
        self.append_row(key, widget)

    def add_vec3(self, key, value):
        x = QLineEdit(value, self)
        y = QLineEdit(value, self)
        z = QLineEdit(value, self)

        lbl = QLabel('')
        lbl.setMinimumWidth(0)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(x, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(y, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(z, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(lbl, stretch=1)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        widget = QWidget(self)
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        setattr(widget, "operator_key", key)
        self.append_row(key, widget)

    def add_vec4(self, key, value):
        x = QLineEdit(value, self)
        y = QLineEdit(value, self)
        z = QLineEdit(value, self)
        w = QLineEdit(value, self)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(x, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(y, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(z, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(w, stretch=1)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        widget = QWidget(self)
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        setattr(widget, "operator_key", key)
        self.append_row(key, widget)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = PropertiesWidget(2)
    ex.begin_group("foo", "foo")
    ex.add_vec2("vec2", "vec2_value")
    ex.add_vec3("vec3", "vec3_value")
    ex.add_vec4("vec4", "vec4_value")
    ex.end_group()

    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If i run it and i extend the widget we'll see all the lineedits are aligned properly on each row:

[image]

But if i shrink it the widgets will be misaligned with different sizes, like this:

[image]

How can i guarantee no matter how you've resized the widget all the **lineedits will have the same size and they will be aligned** each other? I've already tried using setMinimumWidth(100) but that won't do it.

Comment: Put the line-edits in separate columns.

Comment: You mean in different QTreeView's columns instead using the "Value" column? One of the reasons because I'm using just one column is because I'm wrapping a lot of complex widgets to be used on 1 QTreeView cell. For instance, in my original code you'll see methods looking like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21334722/Uploads/2017/01/2017-01-19_12-33-45.txt). That's why i'd like to know how to create proper widgets which guarantee correct proportions. Why setMinimumWidth is not working as i'd expect it btw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**@Avaris** from #pyqt (freenode) channel gave me the solution I was looking for, the main trick was using properly the QSizePolicy on the QLineEdits and empty QLabels, something like this `setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Expanding)` will do the trick. For a full working example, here's a little snippet:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSizePolicy


class VecParameter(QWidget):
    value_changed = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, value, num_components, max_columns=4, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.components = []
        if num_components > max_columns:
            num_components = max_columns

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        for i in range(num_components):
            c = QLineEdit(str(value[i]), self)
            c.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            self.components.append(c)
            layout.addWidget(c, stretch=1)
        for i in range(num_components, max_columns):
            lbl = QLabel('')
            lbl.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            layout.addWidget(lbl, stretch=1)

        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class PropertiesWidget(QTreeView):

    def __init__(self, columns, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PropertiesWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.setColumnCount(columns)
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Property")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Value")
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.last_item = 0
        self.last_item = QStandardItem()
        self.parameters = {}

    def begin_group(self, name, key):
        root = QStandardItem(name)
        root.setEditable(False)
        if not key:
            root.setData(key)
        self.model.appendRow([root])
        self.last_item = root

    def end_group(self):
        if (self.last_item and self.last_item.parent()):
            self.last_item = self.last_item.parent()

    def append_row(self, text, widget):
        if not self.last_item:
            return

        if text in self.parameters:
            raise Exception("Not allowed duplicate keys {0}".format(text))

        item = self.last_item
        child = QStandardItem(text)
        child2 = QStandardItem()
        child.setEditable(False)
        item.appendRow([child, child2])
        if widget:
            self.setIndexWidget(child2.index(), widget)

        self.expand(child.index().parent())

    def add_vec1(self, key, value=[0]):
        widget = VecParameter(value, 1, parent=self)
        self.append_row(key, widget)

    def add_vec2(self, key, value=[0, 0]):
        widget = VecParameter(value, 2, parent=self)
        self.append_row(key, widget)

    def add_vec3(self, key, value=[0, 0, 0]):
        widget = VecParameter(value, 3, parent=self)
        self.append_row(key, widget)

    def add_vec4(self, key, value=[0, 0, 0, 0]):
        widget = VecParameter(value, 4, parent=self)
        self.append_row(key, widget)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = PropertiesWidget(2)
    ex.begin_group("foo", "foo")
    ex.add_vec1("vec1", [1])
    ex.add_vec2("vec2", [1, 2])
    ex.add_vec3("vec3", [1, 2, 3])
    ex.add_vec4("vec4", [1, 2, 3, 4])
    ex.end_group()

    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Actualy your layouts does not have the same amount of items. Thats why. Every "line" you have must have the same lenght but with different amount of items. so when you are making it smaller, the space is divided with the items inside.

For a quick workaround your can try to add "invisible" items like spacers to your layouts, so the sum of the items in each line can be the same

Answer (score -3):

You could use Tkinter to do this. It is much simpler and will keep everything aligned with its grid feature! (Just be sure to set the x offset for each box!)

```
Import tkinter

root = tk.Tk() # Some versions of python throw tantrums when you don't do this
root.geometry(...) #Like so: root.geometry("400x400")
#to make this easy I'll only do one box.
"""
The grid feature of tkinter allows you to grid-align boxes to a page.
By just simply asking if root.geometry is less than ... then realign to a new grid.
"""
Entry = tkinter.Entry(root, background = "...") #Use Entry.get() feature to gather what's been written as a value called ans if u want to do this.
#More entries down here.....
Entry.grid(row = 2, column = 2) #Edit row and column for where to grid it.
root.mainloop() # Required by tkinter in order to run.
```

Comment: Your answer does not match the question, clearly he wants to use PyQt and not Tkinter

Comment: This wouldn't even answer the question if the user was using Tkinter, since the layouts are in separate leaves of a tree-view.

Comment: Thanks for the effort of your answer but as @ekhumoro said, my question is related to pyqt. For instance, the posted code is a minimal example of a larger widget i'm using on a larger project, so you just can't say "use this other tech" to solve a little issue that i'm sure can be solved with pyqt (even if i don't know how) ;)